# Where’s my toilet drain

Tags: plumbing, toilet

What is this metal sleeve? The plumber put this on when I wasn’t at the house. Do I just cut it flush to the floor and there’s a PVC pipe inside?

[image]

Comment: Was this new construction, replacing an existing toilet?  It looks like a protective sleeve to tile around. Try  pulling it straight up. Maybe include a picture inside it.